# getting information from the database using mysql and codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

an update from my previous question..

this is my code in the model.

```
function member_here()
{
$this->db->select('');
$this->db->from('membership');
$this->db->where('username',$this->input->post('username'));

$q=$this->db->get();

if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
$data = array('first_name');
foreach($q->result() as $row) {
    $data=$row;
}
return $data;
}
}
```

and this is my code in the view form:

```
<?php


$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->model('membership_model');
$result = $CI->membership_model->member_here();
print_r($result);
?>
```

now. i have a problem.

the output is this:

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 10 [first_name] => Marishka [last_name] => Villamin [username] => marishkapv [password] => 01aef487205966f24dd694ca4153ccbb [email_address] => marishkapv@gmail.com )
```

i dont need that output. instead i want my output to be **Marishka** which is the value of the first_name field.

help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo $result->first_name;
```

You just need to echo out the part of the object you want, not the entire object. And for the record you shouldn't be getting any data from the model in the view, that should all be done in the controller.

Comment: You're quite welcome. I would suggest you check out these tutorials http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/codeigniter-from-scratch/  They were a great help to me when I started CI. They'll help you understand the MVC concept too.

Comment: follow up question though. i am getting the results i want. but the problem is, the output is the last row in the database.

lets say i have 3 rows and I logged in using the 1st user name, it is echoing the 3rd user's infromation.

i have been watching that! you answered my question before and your suggestion did a lot for me, i was able to do what i was doing and it helped me too :)

Comment: That makes no sense at all to be honest, not with the code above at least. Are you sure the usernames are different?

Comment: Yes. The usernames are different. Sorry. I should make it clear. there are 3 people in my database. johndoe, marishka and dennis. if I log in   any of the three, it outputs the information for dennis. is it my foreach thats making the results wrong?

Comment: I think theres something wrong with my:

$this->db->where('username',$this->input->post('username'));

Comment: Is username the name of the input field in your login form? Try putting echo $this->input->post('username'); die; as the first two lines in your model and make sure the model is getting the data you expect it to.

Comment: Yes. The username is the input field in the login form :)

Comment: Sorry. echo $this->input->post('username'); die; didnt work. its really confusing. this is my process.. im not sure if im explaining it correct. im in the login view which i think is loading the validate function in my login controller, then to the login model then goes back to the controller for confirmation then it goes to the home view(where i want to output the information of the user who logged in) is it clear?? im not sure if im explaining it correct i might not have said the correct terms. sorry :)

Comment: No you're explaining fine. Trust me watch those tutorials I linked earlier, in fact I believe there is one on creating a login. You're going about this completely backwards and you need a more solid understanding of the MVC concept. The way this should work is simple. You have a view that takes the input of username and passord and passes that to a Controller function that verifies the data, if it verifies it passes that the input to a model to retrieve the records which returns the data to the controller to pass to either the same view or a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem has been solved, but next time, you could specify the particular column you wish to fetch from your database.

```
function member_here()
{
    //This is where your specify the column
    $this->db->select('first_name');
    $this->db->from('membership');
    $this->db->where('username',$this->input->post('username'));

    $q=$this->db->get();

    if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        $data = array('first_name');
        foreach($q->result() as $row) {
            $data=$row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Like so..

I hope this was helpful

Comment: i still have a problem though. its not just the first name i am trying to select thats why i left it blank. but the thing is, instead of echoing the data for that specific username, it echoes the data of a different username. to be exact. lets say i have 3 people in my database. johndoe, marishka and dennis. i logged in john doe, so it means when i go to the home page. john doe's information must appear. instead, the information of dennis is being displayed. i dont know which part went wrong. i am now stuck. please help. thank you so much!